# In which case PHP sort function returns FALSE?

Tags: php, sorting

PHP [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function and other functions from this family returns 
**true** on success or **false** on failure. In which case sort function returns **false**? What is possible source of failure?

**Example:**

```
$array = [1, 5, 22, 8, 3, 3];
$returnValue = sort($array);
var_dump($returnValue);   // bool(true)
```

I can't imagine any case in which `$returnValue` could be **false**.

I have also tried sort variants with user-defined comparison function, which can possibly introduce some error, but with no success.

```
$array = [1, 5, 22, 8, 3, 3];
$returnValue = usort($array, function($a, $b) { return 'Hello World'; });
var_dump($returnValue);   // bool(true)
```

Actually you can do whatever you want in your comparison function, because callback's return value is internally 
casted to integer, and you will get `$returnValue === true` everytime. This also applies for user-defined comparison function
without returned value. PHP returns **null** in this case, which is internally casted to integer: `(int)null === 0`
and thus everything is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure since I have never tried this, but maybe passing a value to sort() that is NOT an array will cause a return of false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will return false if parameter one is not an array

Comment: Simple answer. I have never thought about passing different parameter than array.